# SpecFlow C# Regex optional parameter in double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, specflow

I want to write step definition, that will work for either of three steps below.
I need to make last two parameters in double quotes optional.

```
Given I do "x"
Given I do "x", "y "
Given I do "x", "y ", " z"
```

I've tried several expressions:

```
[Given(@"I do ""(.*)"", ""(.*)?"", ""(.*)?""")]
[Given(@"I do ""(.*)"", ""(.*)""?, ""(.*)""?")]
[Given(@"I do ""(.*)"", (""(.*)"")?, (""(.*)"")?")]
[Given(@"I do ""(.*)"", [""(.*)""]?, [""(.*)""]?")]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this matches/groups what you're trying to match

```
I do \"(.*?)\"(?:, \"(.*?)\")?(?:, \"(.*?)\")?
```

[Regexr Example](https://regexr.com/3os2v)

Comment: Excellent. I have actually tried non-matching group, but forgot to include the coma and space inside non-matching group bracket. Thank you!

Comment: @Razkar I will admit having capturing groups inside of non-capturing groups is a bit messy.  But this is regex, so that's kinda the point!  Also, don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: One thing I have to do though is use "" instead of \"
[Given(@"I do ""(.*)""(?:, ""(.*)?"")?(?:, ""(.*)?"")?]

Comment: @Razkar I'm guessing that's a `C#` thing, I'm not sure as I'm a filthy python-only dev.

Comment: It is. It's a c# verbatim string, starting with @

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
I do \".*?\"(?:, \".*?\")*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EL6B8o/2)

Explanation:

```
/I do \".*?\"(?:, \".*?\")*/
    I do  matches the characters I do  literally (case sensitive)
    \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
    .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
    \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
    Non-capturing group (?:, \".*?\")*
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
        ,  matches the characters ,  literally (case sensitive)
        \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
        .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
        \" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
```